# Access data member of a class with reference of type 'Object'

Tags: java

I have tried accessing the data member of a class Student via reference of 'Object' class (which is a base class of all classes in Java) but, the compiler throws a compile-time error.

**Code**:

```java
class Student {
  String name;
  int roll;
  public Student(String name, int roll) {
    this.name = name;
    this.roll = roll;
  }
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object ob[] = new Object[4];
    Student s = new Student("Yash", 88);
    ob[0] = s;

    System.out.println(s.name);
    System.out.println(ob[0].name);
  }
}
```

**Output (Compile-time Error)**:

```sh
Main.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.println(ob[0].name);
                            ^
  symbol:   variable name
  location: class Object
1 error
compiler exit status 1
```

Both, the instance as well as the pointer belong to same class:

```java
System.out.println(s.getClass());
System.out.println(ob[0].getClass());
```

Output:

```sh
class Student
class Student
```

Comment: That's a compile-time error, not a runtime error. And don't call references pointers. Call them references.

Comment: rectified, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tldr; You'll still need to cast it:

```
System.out.println(((Student)ob[0]).name);
```

When you were trying `ob[0].name` you were seeing it before compile time. Since it hasn't been compiled, the compiler doesn't know yet that it is of type `Student`. But after compiling it, the runtime variable changes when you call `ob[0]=s`, which is why `ob[0].getclass()` works.

Comment: The explanation, you provided, is what I was seeking. It helped me understand the concept in a broad and better way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You ***can*** cast the `Object` to `Student`, alternatively you could use *reflection*

```
System.out.println(Student.class.getDeclaredField("name").get(ob[0]));
```

or

```
System.out.println(((Student) ob[0]).name);
```

or make it an array of `Student`(s) in the first place.

```
Student[] ob = new Student[4];
ob[0] = new Student("Yash", 88);
System.out.println(ob[0].name);
```